# How to add/subtract an array of varying Month timedeltas in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, datetimeoffset

I wish to subtract some number of months from a datetime column. Each row has a different number of months to subtract. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.date_range('2017-10-01', '2018-10-01', freq='m'),
    'delta_in_months': [1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3]
})
```

The outcome should look as so (the day rounding irrelevant, it could be 01 or 28/29/30/31, it was easier to type in 01),

```
    timestamp   delta_in_months  new_timestamp
0   2017-10-31  1                2017-09-01
1   2017-11-30  4                2017-07-01
2   2017-12-31  2                2017-10-01
3   2018-01-31  5                2017-08-01
4   2018-02-28  1                2018-01-01
5   2018-03-31  3                2017-12-01
6   2018-04-30  1                2018-03-01
7   2018-05-31  5                2017-12-01
8   2018-06-30  2                2018-04-01
9   2018-07-31  4                2018-03-01
10  2018-08-31  1                2018-07-01
11  2018-09-30  3                2018-06-01
```

Bear in mind that this will be for a much larger dataframe.

---

I have tried,

```
months_delta = df.delta_in_months.apply(pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset)
df['new_timestamp'] = df.timestamp - months_delta
```

but this gave very unexpected results, with each row entry being a DatetimeIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try

```
df['new_timestamp'] = df.timestamp - pd.to_timedelta(df.delta_in_months,unit='M')
df['new_timestamp'] = df['new_timestamp'].dt.date
```

One important thing is to remember that **1 'M'**  =  **30 'D'**.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think to try this because 'M' was not listed in the `pd.to_timedelta` docs :'(

Comment: I have now raised this on [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23248) as an issue.

Comment: yes. I sew the 'D' so I tried the same with 'M'. One important thing is to remember that 1 'M' = 30 'D'.

Comment: I think you should add that to your answer as, over a long period, it could affect the month you fall into.

Comment: Units 'M' and 'Y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations.

Comment: it is often unacceptable to approximate an offset of 1 month by "30 days".

Comment: Units 'M', 'Y', and 'y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations.

Answer (score 3):

If you are landing here because you were searching for a **vectorized, fast and correct** solution to the problem of adding a variable number of months to a `Series` of `Timestamps`, then read on.

In some problems, we do indeed want to add actual months (the way `pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x)` works), i.e.: `2021-01-31 + 1 month --> 2021-02-28`, and not just "30 days". But trying to use `pd.offsets.DateOffset` directly raises a warning (`PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized` ). For example:

- `dates + df['months'].apply(lambda m: pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=m))`
- `dates + months * pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)`, which additionally is wrong in some cases (e.g. `2015-07-29 + 59 months` should be `2020-06-29`, not `2020-06-28`).

Instead, we can do a bit of arithmetic ourselves and get a vectorized solution:

```py
# note: not timezone-aware
def vadd_months(dates, months):
    ddt = dates.dt
    m = ddt.month - 1 + months
    mb = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({
        'year': ddt.year + m // 12,
        'month': (m % 12) + 1,
        'day': 1})) + (dates - dates.dt.normalize())
    me = mb + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
    r = mb + (ddt.day - 1) * pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    r = np.minimum(r, me)
    return r
```

**Usage for the OP example**

```py
df['new_timestamp'] = vadd_months(df['timestamp'], df['delta_in_months'])
```

**Speed**

```py
n = int(100_000)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(
            pd.Timestamp('2000').value,
            pd.Timestamp('2020').value,
            n
        ))).dt.floor('1s'),
    'months': np.random.randint(0, 120, n),
})

%%time
newts = vadd_months(df['timestamp'], df['months'])
# CPU times: user 52.3 ms, sys: 4.01 ms, total: 56.3 ms
```

**Verification**

Check with the (non-vectorized) direct use of `pd.offsets.DateOffset`:

```py
import warnings

%%time
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=pd.errors.PerformanceWarning)
    check = df['timestamp'] + df['months'].apply(lambda m: pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=m))
# CPU times: user 2.41 s, sys: 43.9 ms, total: 2.45 s

>>> newts.equals(check)
True
```

Note that `vadd_months` is 40x faster than the non-vectorized version, and there are no warnings to catch.